# Binary Bob's Programming Language Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

## Binary Bob Needs Your Assistance

[image: Bob is Confused]

### Bob's Dilemma

Binary Bob is considering going back to school to learn computer programming, however, Bob has been given some jumbled course information.

Bob needs your help so he can make an informed decision. If he fails, I suppose he will just go golfing!

Using **only** the clues below, match each of the course names to its associated cost, to the number of weeks length of the course.

### Clue: 1

The Visual Basic Course costs $2.00 more than the course that is 2 weeks long.

### Clue: 2

The $3.00 course is 4 weeks long.

### Clue: 3

Of the C# course and the $6.00 course, one is 7 weeks long and the other is 4 weeks long.

### Clue: 4

4. The Fortran course costs $4.00.

> **Note**: Remember, no option in any category will ever be used more than once.

Available Clue Answers

```
PRICE
$3.00     
$4.00
$5.00
$6.00

COURSES
JAVASCRIPT
FORTRAN
VISUAL BASIC
C# SHARP

DURATION OF COURSE
7 WEEK COURSE
2 WEEK COURSE
5 WEEK COURSE
4 WEEK COURSE
```

Comment: My company purchased this image along with the rest of the bundle from DreamsTime, and according to their terms, we can use the images as we wish. That's what we buy thousands of credits for. :)  It is nice though to have someone looking out for other designers, like myself. I found a business card of ours on PSD key torrent site last week. Still had our company name on it!

Comment: LOL Brandon, yes. I am a 52 year old business owner who has been in the Managed Services Industry for 11 years. I assure you, I will follow the rules of the site to the letter. If creating custom art is going to take away from the enjoyment of the users and shift the focus from learning, fun, and challenging ourselves - I will not dress up my posts any longer. I signed up here to share my Mathematics knowledge and passion for puzzles, not to debate the ownership rights of an .11 cent jpg. I do, however, realize you probably have to deal with all sorts of characters, so no hard feelings here.:)

Comment: Thanks for putting my mind to rest. I really appreciate you taking the time to letter out what is going on. The custom art is great (and encouraged!), but we do get a fair amount of copycat puzzles on the site, which is why I was suspicious/cynical when I saw the image elsewhere. I suppose my previous comments no longer contribute here, so I'm going to delete them. Again, thanks for being patient and understanding that I was trying to make sure that the site doesn't run into any legal problems (that would be very sad).

Comment: Wow somehow I missed your reply @Brandon_J , and I do think my following comment adds value to the site, and question.  I think what makes StackExchange and StackO so resourceful is having users such as yourself. This site and its users do their best to filter out info that is not valuable. Improper use of art does not add to the value of this site, or any question posted, so again I do applaud you for your attentiveness. I am new still, and learning the ways here. Thank you for being a respectful StackExchange user who gently guided a newbie. Regards, John.

Comment: And StackExchange is made even better by people like _you_ who put up with the self-appointed quality control managers around here and post great content ;) Will we be seeing any other puzzles soon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the clues 4, then 2, then 3, then 1 yields

> ```
>  
> PRICE     COURSE      DURATION
>
> $3.00     C#          4 weeks
>
> $4.00     Fortran     2 weeks
>
> $5.00     Javascript  5 weeks
>
> $6.00     VB          7 weeks
> ```

Comment: By the way does anyone know how to `>!` such formatted display? And/or how to `>!` a bullet list?

Comment: Someone did it for me once...I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Oh, here it is: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/im-trying-to-create-a-magic-square/80229#80229

Comment: The dollar signs mess it up. Because of course they do. I did it a slightly different way.

Comment: Thanks @Rubio. A combo with Brandon's method yields an even better result.